# What does 'campy' mean?

Tags: terminology

What does it mean when people say that a bike part is "campy"?

I've heard people say "campy hub" and "campy chain", for example.

Comment: The one exception would be a campy rider... that's something *completely* different.

Comment: @Criggie [Indeed](http://blog.truffleshuffle.co.uk/index.php/2011/06/cycling-superheroes/)!

Comment: Aussies might also say "campag" meaning the same company.

Comment: BTW https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/campy

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for Campagnolo.

Comment: I believe that it may be the US abbreviation for Campagnolo. I believe the UK may say Campag, e.g. in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Fx45RBgY4U  I'm not certain about Commonwealth countries.

Comment: In that case, the question is irrelevant for UK readers.

Answer (score 18):

"Campy" is an affectionate name for Campagnolo, an Italian bicycle parts manufacturer. The reason why you see it specifically mentioned in many cases (whereas you don't see Shimano/SRAM mentioned) is that the parts are rarer (and more expensive) and often incompatible with Shimano/SRAM (though Zinn notes [it may be accidentally getting better](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/09/bikes-and-tech/drivetrain-compatibility-hidden-in-plain-sight_303199)). Shimano/SRAM have some compatibility with each other (e.g. chains, cassettes, freehubs) and some incompatibility (e.g. shifters), but they're far more incompatible with Campagnolo.

Comment: Besides which, no one can remember how to spell (or even pronounce) "Campagnolo", whereas Shimano and SRAM are easy.

Comment: Campagnolo isn't hard to pronounce if you look at the word and actually say it

Comment: @DanielRHicks "Campagnolo" is no harder to spell or pronounce than "lasagne".

Comment: To be fair, I practically never see lasagne used -- just lasagna. And I don't think its all too easy to pronounce, especially if Campy is not used in your area very often (for example, the nearest Campy dealer is over 120 miles / 200 km away from where I live, so you rarely hear people talk about it).

Comment: @DavidRicherby - "Lasagne" is easy to spell if you know how to pronounce it -- la-sahg-knee.

Comment: @Batman Lasagne/lasagna -- no particular difference. In Italian, they're plural and singular, respectively, but English seems to use them interchangeably.

Comment: @DanielRHicks And it's exactly the same pattern in "Campagnolo". How can one of them be easy but the other hard?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Like I said no one (who doesn't deal with the stuff regularly) can remember how to pronounce "Campagnolo".  It's generally pronounced as a mumble.

Comment: To be fair, for SRAM, you hear S-Ram and Schram/Shram and some others. Shimano is the only one I think that everyone uses the same.

Comment: @Batman and very few western people pronounce Shimano correctly, because most people Anglicise it. The guy in the LBS probably wouldn't know what you meant of you did say it properly.

Comment: This is how it sounds: https://youtu.be/AVnZ7cWEIcc?t=10s. My friend uses Campa-YOLO and gives 0 f's :)

Comment: @andy256 - fine, nobody can pronounce any of the current major drivetrain manufacturers normally sans Microshift.